# Statement between for loops in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, loops, for-loop

I'm trying get printed array of 3x3 but it only prints first two rows on Xcode, but it's working fine on other compilers.

```
int arr[3][3]={1,2,3,  
               4,5,6,  
               7,8,9 
             };  
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{  
    printf("\n");   

    // printf("i=%d",i);  

    for (int j=0; j<3;j++){
        printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. What compiler do you use?

Comment: You need to print a newline after the outer loop finishes.

Comment: Move your `printf \n` after the 2nd for loop.

Comment: @FredK Better yet, move the printing of the new line before the inner loop to after the inner loop.

Comment: It is not so much a function of the compiler, which produces the code you tell it to, but how the buffering works in the OS.

Comment: @WeatherVane That does tend to be true, but the output should all be flushed at the end of the program anyway.

Comment: How are you running/compiling this code? XCode has various options, including a playground.